# Dubbio riguardo all'uso dell'avverbio "vicariamente"

Tags: translation

Soffermandomi sul testo di una canzone (Tool - *Vicariously*), mi sono chiesto se appunto il titolo di questa fosse traducibile in qualche modo in italiano.

Prendendolo letteralmente avremmo, come scritto sopra, "vicariamente", ma, oltre a suonare non proprio bene, non credo sia nemmeno una parola italiana, in quanto, cercandola su Google, non escono risultati chiarificatori (in spagnolo invece esiste).

Il significato di questa parola comunque è tipo "[vivere una certa esperienza] in modo indiretto, tramite azioni di un'altra persona".

Ditemi voi se può esistere questa forma avverbiale anche nella lingua italiana.

Comment: Hai provato a cercare su qualche dizionario? Una ricerca rapida porta le espressioni "per interposta persona", "indirettamente" o "di riflesso". Non sono sicuro che una traduzione esatta esista, ma già questi suggerimenti potrebbero essere appropriati, a seconda del contesto.

Comment: Cercando su Google Libri si trovano alcuni esempi di uso di "vicariamente" in italiano. Per esempio: https://books.google.es/books?id=sRE8AAAAIAAJ&q=vicariamente&dq=vicariamente&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIub-MrprhAhWiDmMBHcVSA1s4ChDoAQgdMAU.

Comment: Avevo provato a cercare su un paio di dizionari (Corriere e Treccani) ma non ho trovato nulla...

Answer (score 1):

Onestamente l'avverbio "vicariamente" suona piuttosto male. Sarebbe meglio utilizzare la locuzione "da/come vicario" o "indirettamente". Eppure la parola potrebbe tranquillamente esistere dato che il sostantivo "vicario" può anche avere funzione di aggettivo (e.g. "*Coprire una funzione vicaria.*") e quindi collegarsi al suffisso "-mente" per creare un avverbio derivato. Comunque sia, **sono quasi certo che il vocabolo in questione non esista**.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Tuttavia, su Google Libri si trovano alcune occorrenze.

Comment: Non ha molto senso dire che una parola “non esiste”. A parte che nel momento in cui qualcuno la usa esiste, la cosa più importante è che la lingua italiana (come le altre lingue naturali) ha meccanismi per cui da una parola se ne possono creare numerose altre: avverbi, superlativi, termini composti, voci flesse etc., spesso non registrate sui dizionari, se non hanno un significato o delle connotazioni a sé stanti.

Comment: Però andiamoci piano @DaG... inventare parole nega lo scopo principale di una lingua: farsi comprendere attraverso un mezzo conosciuto e condiviso. Quindi credo che si possano coniare nuove parole se il loro significato è facilmente derivabile e quindi comprensibile (vicariamente è un buon esempio), senza troppe ambiguità, se non esistono già parole adatte, e sperabilmente in un contesto preciso. Tra l'altro, non abbiamo forse troppa paura di non essere concisi? Che male c'è nel dire "da vicario" invece di "vicariamente"? Poi, *da vicario* è pure più breve!

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: “Andiamoci piano” è un'espressione curiosa da usare rivolgendosi a qualcuno che non è un tuo amico, non trovi? Forse persino più di “vicariamente”. Prova a rileggere quello che ho scritto: “ci vado piano” eccome e non ho mai parlato di “inventare” parole, bensì dei meccanismi standard di derivazione lessicale. Ma soprattutto non ho mai difeso la parola “vicariamente”, ma solo fatto qualche considerazione su che cosa vuol dire che una parola esiste o no. È più chiaro, adesso?

Comment: @DaG non volevo essere invadente e chiedo scusa. Il Suo commento iniziava con "non ha molto senso dire che una parola non esiste": io ho voluto dire che per me ha invece moltissimo senso, pur ricordando che, quando appropriato, si può fare. Ho letto e riletto il Suo commento: continuo a intenderlo come prima. Infine, non trovo che *andiamoci piano* sia irrispettoso, per questo e non per altro ho scritto così; ognuno ha una propria sensibilità, oppure io sono ignorante.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Sai bene che in forum e siti come questi ci si dà del tu. Cerco di spiegarmi meglio, anche perché al di là del gusto polemico di entrambi, stiamo dicendo la stessa cosa. “Inventare” le parole significherebbe dire “kneflsbjhabx” anziché “cucchiaio”, e siamo tutti d'accordo che creerebbe solo problemi (se non fatto per gioco, con intento poetico come Fosco Maraini o simili). (segue)

Comment: (segue) Io parlo invece dei “meccanismi per cui da una parola se ne possono creare numerose altre: avverbi, superlativi, termini composti, voci flesse etc.”. Siamo nello stesso ambito di quello che dici tu quando parli di “coniare nuove parole se il loro significato è facilmente derivabile e quindi comprensibile”, no?

Comment: Per chiarirmi ancora meglio. È ovvio a tutti che la parola “kneflsbjhabx” _non esiste_: non c'è nemmeno bisogno di parlarne. La zona grigia interessante è per parole come “supercoltellino”, “velocissimissimo”, “quasiamico”, “petaloso”, “portasmartphone”, “cicciosamente”, che, registrate o meno che siano nella pratica, trasmettono un senso, e spesso anche una connotazione (scherzosa, allusiva, affettuosa) a qualunque parlante italiano, grazie al fatto di essere formate con radici, prefissi, suffissi e meccanismi che sono, loro sì, parte integrante dell'italiano. È più chiaro, adesso?

Comment: Sì @DaG, nella forma siamo polemici (o pignoli?) entrambi. Nel merito credo che siamo posizionati diversamente in quella zona grigia che dici. Butto a caso alcuni pensieri: chissà se Charo si diverte a leggere termini astrusi, per poi cercarli sui dizionari e infine fare domande su questo forum. Se lei si diverte, altri lettori forse si divertono meno. Poi, la Crusca ha un ruolo, i dizionari hanno un ruolo, io non sono ne' la Crusca ne' un dizionario. Sono più libero, credo, di difendere l'Italiano da ignoranza, sciatteria e scimmiotteria (segue)

Comment: (segue) per @dag. Per questo, il concetto "se qualcuno pronuncia una parola allora quella parola esiste", messo retoricamente all'inizio di un commento (che poi cambia tono, ma in questo consiste la retorica), m'è parso pericoloso. Specialmente in calce a un post che vorrebbe prendere il titolo di una canzone inglese e riportarlo in italiano storpiato; una veloce ricerca (https://www.wordreference.com/enit/vicariously) suggerisce per *vicariamente* un semplice "indirettamente". Mi pare che *vicario* abbia un significato alquanto diverso dall'equivalente inglese. Era troppo, non ho resistito